# ldapsearch: How do I query pwdLastSet and have it make sense?

Tags: ldap

Hi all I have same problem as here: [enter link description here](https://serverfault.com/questions/58720/powershell-how-do-i-query-pwdlastset-and-have-it-make-sense), but I need it for ldapserach not in Powershell.

my command:

```
ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://<HOST>:<POST> -D 'CN=<CN>' -w <PASSWD> '(samaccountname=<NAME>)' pwdlastset
```

output:

```
dn: <SOME_DN>
pwdLastSet: 131267839972407395
```

Comment: Try with `ldapsearch -LLL -H ldap://<HOST>:<POST> -D 'CN=<CN>' -w <PASSWD> '(samaccountname=<NAME>)' pwdlastset | perl -pne 's/(\d{11})\d{7}/scalar(localtime($1-11644473600))/e'`

Answer (score 0):

You get a filetime attribute back by the query. It is defined as `100-nanoseconds since Jan 1 1601`.

You can convert that with any modern programming language.

For example in bash

```
date -d "1601/1/1+$(expr $filetime / 10000000 )Seconds"
```

or Python

```
datetime(1601,1,1) + timedelta(microseconds=filetime/10)
```